# Is It Possible to Pull Up/Down Vote Data & Track ID from di.fm and Insert into a Database (e.g. MySQL)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

So a music streaming site, [di.fm](http://di.fm) has a up/down vote system. I've been looking at the page source, and this chunk of code looks to be the part that deals with the up vote buttons/stats:

```
<div class="vote-count up">  <span class="icon icon-thumbs-up"></span>  <span class="count">[%= track.votes.up %]</span>
```

As a musician I want to do some data analysis and basically curate a database that pulls the up/down vote info associated with each track and have some sort of CreateOrUpdate function tied to a database of some sort to perform queries on. Based on the above snippet, is it even possible to develop something that runs in the background to do this, and if so, I can I grab said info on said programming platform (and do a database CreateOrUpdate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

It will, however, violate the [terms of service](http://www.di.fm/member/tos):

> You agree that you will **not use any robot, spider, scraper or other automated means** to access the Website for any purpose without our express written permission.

Do you have a written permission?

If you want to take the legal risk of getting sued by them:

1. do *not* ask others to do the dirty work for you.
2. [import.io](http://import.io/) is an app designed for making such tasks easier to do yourself.
3. Let me repeat: the terms of service do not allow this type of access, so I advise to not do this.

Comment: Alright, should have probably scrounged for a ToS first. :(